# ID variable changes over time, how to calculate pct change by ID

Tags: r, dplyr

The problem starts from the difficulty of explaining it.

I have a data set that has a time dimension, my ID variables change name over time making it difficult to calculate e.g. percentage changes over time by ID variable.

```
ID YR   Value
01 2004 100
02 2005 50 
03 2005 50
04 2005 10
```

I need to calculate pct. Change in Value over time by ID. The problem is in Yr 2005 the ID variable 01 is split into three `IDs (02,03,04)`, such that one has to aggregate the values for the three IDs in 2005 to get the corresponding value for `ID 01 in 2005`. The percent change of `ID 01` is NOT `50/100`, rather `sum(50,50,10)/100`.

I have data.frame of IDs only matching the changes over time, it looks like this:

```
x2004 x2005
01    01
01    02
01    03
```

I used group_by from `dplyr` to create matching between IDs in the two years

```
group_by(x2004) %>% 
  summarize(onetomany = paste(sort(unique(x2005)),collapse=", "))
```

Which gave me a data.frame of the form

```
  cv2004 onetomany
1      1 1, 2, 3
```

Where I can see which IDs belong to the same group, and that is where I stopped the percentage calculation.

I totally understand that the problem it self is not easy to understand. This is a common problem in trade statistics, commodity codes change name over time but not content, and one has to keep track of the changes to get the picture of developments in trade over time by commodity. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The example data.frame I provided changed into a plain text, I do not know how to keep it formatted.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame("ID" =  c("01", "02", "03", "04"),
                 "YR" = c(2004, 2005, 2005, 2005),
                 "Value" = c(100, 50, 50, 10))
df %>% group_by(YR) %>% summarise(sum = sum(Value))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
     YR   sum
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2004   100
2  2005   110
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the data better. It's not clear what your base is that you want to reference or why you want 2005 to be an average. Maybe it would help just to reference each value to your base? If 2004 at 100 is your base, then it looks like your answers are good, as is. OTOH, if you really want average by year, is this what you want?

Comment: I have 16 years of data and thousands of IDs some of which split or merge to a new ones overtime. The example I provided is the case where ID 01 splits into three (01,02,03), so that the Value in period 2005 is 110 (=sum(50,50,10)), and the pct. change will be (110/100)-1. I want my program to do this automatically for future periods too. Any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of mean in the summarise(), use sum: df %>% group_by(YR) %>% summarise(sum = sum(Value))